# C# and Access: Query input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: c#, ms-access

im trying to take the id from table TEAM and put into Clients when i inserted some clients.. but..
I have this error when it should insert into my database.

> ```
>      System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>     Query input must contain at least one table or query.
> ```

```
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(stringcon);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[Idteam]) " +
                    "VALUES(@f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,(select team.id from team where team.Email=@email)) ";

                // cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata]) " +
                //"VALUES(@f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg) ";


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", materialSingleLineTextField16.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", materialSingleLineTextField15.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", materialSingleLineTextField14.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph", materialSingleLineTextField13.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", materialSingleLineTextField6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser", materialSingleLineTextField3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", materialSingleLineTextField2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", gender);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cui", materialSingleLineTextField4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", materialSingleLineTextField5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pd", richTextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@te", bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prov", bunifuDropdown2.selectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH: mm:ss"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Form1.Email);


                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

So.. i tried something like that with `SQL` and it works but in this format doesn't work. I really need to do this with `Olebd`.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[Idteam]) " +
            "Select @f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,team.[id] from team where team.[Email]=@email";
```

Comment: Why are you not trying what @ErikvonAsmuth wrote in his answer? What you have there is **not** the same as what ErikvonAsmuth wrote below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use subqueries in an `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` query. You need to use an `INSERT INTO .. SELECT`. Since you're not using a main query to select from, you might as well do that instead of using a subquery.

Use the following SQL instead of your current SQL string

```
INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[Idteam]) 
SELECT @f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg, team.id 
from team 
where team.Email=@email
```

Note that, if the email is not unique, multiple rows for every `team.id` with that `team.Email` will be inserted.

Comment: the email is unique, i tried as u said but it gives me another error " System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'team.id from team where team.Email=@email'.'  "

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[Idteam]) " +
                "VALUES(@f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,team.id from team where team.Email=@email) ";

Comment: That's not the SQL I shared. No `Values`! Read my answer again.

Comment: Ok, i read again your answer, and do not give me the same error, but it gives me this '  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'      i put the command in topic.

Comment: Share your implementation. You did that wrong last time.

Comment: Ok. im sorry  i do not know why I did the opposite,  right now i did as you said, as u wrote. But now it said: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Comment: Ok. It works, i put id and email in [ ], so thank you.. im sorry for my little unseen.